# UWP: DependencyProperty propertyChangedCallback not firing when set to null

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, uwp

Title says it all...

The code of my DependencyProperty is the following:

```
public object IsChecked
{
    get { return GetValue(IsCheckedProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsChecked", typeof(object),
                                                              typeof(MyCheckbox), 
                                                              new PropertyMetadata(false, IsCheckedChanged));

private static void IsCheckedChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var checkbox = d as MyCheckbox;
    bool? newvalue = null;
    if (e.NewValue is bool?)
        newvalue = (bool?)e.NewValue;
    else if (e.NewValue != null)
    {
        bool newbool;
        if (!bool.TryParse(e.NewValue.ToString(), out newbool))
            return;
        newvalue = newbool;
    }
    if (checkbox != null && !checkbox.Checked.Equals(newvalue))
        checkbox.Checked = newvalue;
}
```

I bind to that property like this:

```
<local:MyCheckbox IsChecked="{Binding Stata,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Stata implemented like this:

```
private bool? _stata = null;
public bool? Stata
{
    get { return _stata; }
    set
    {
        _stata = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

When Stata changes to "true", MyCheckbox updates as expected. However, when Stata starts as null or changes to null, MyCheckbox doesn't get the update, IsCheckedChanged doesn't fire.

If I change the default value of my property to null like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("IsChecked",
        typeof(object),
        typeof(MyCheckbox),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, IsCheckedChanged));
```

It again works as expected, `IsCheckedChanged` is called whenever `Stata` changes to/from `true`/`false` and `null`.

Is this a bug? I want my default value to be `false`, not `null`, how can I realize this?

**Edit:** I have uploaded a sample solution to GitHub, while the Changed functions get called now, the shown result is different for UWP when the value is `null`
You can find the repository here: https://github.com/ManIkWeet/DependencyPropertyTest

Comment: Is there any reason why you declare the property as `object` instead of `bool?`.

Comment: Yes, if you declare it as `bool?` you can't set it to  `{x:Type Null}` in XAML

Comment: You probably want to set it to `{x:Null}`, not `{x:Type Null}`. That works perfectly for me with a property of type `bool?`.

Comment: You seem to be right, however this still doesn't solve the original question.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/07/lets-code-in-winrt-xaml-you-cannot.html. Strange enough...

Comment: I did read that, I believe that is why I used `object` instead of `bool?`. In normal .NET `bool?` works, in UWP it gives the error: `Converter failed to convert value of type 'Windows.Foundation.Boolean' to type 'IReference'1<Boolean>';`

Answer (score 1):

When you click your checkbox the value becomes a local value and the binding is lost. You can use commands to update your state. There are many articles on how to do this.

When debugging you might have noticed two things. 1) The stack is different and I also noticed 2) An error in the output window: Converter failed to convert value of type 'Windows.Foundation.Boolean' to type 'IReference`1' Now searching for this I found : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e4e6bf30-0493-4ede-b20e-25a5d3ffe79e/nullablet-dependency-properties-and-binding The root-cause appears to be com-based which doesn't support nullables.

Comment: While this is true (thanks!), this is not the answer for my original question. In the original question I never click the checkbox, the Stata binding changes by another source.

Comment: What source triggers the change? Because I've made a sample triggering a Stata change through another checkbox and IsCheckedChanged fires correctly.

Comment: A Binding to a value in a different DataContext with a converter. Let's see if I can make a demo on GitHub...